# No connection pool with 'primary' found for RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have a fresh Rails 6 codebase with a pg database and am getting an error when trying to run a simple rspec test. What might be the issue here?

```
  1) SomeModel Object Itself sets the name correctly
 Failure/Error: m = SomeModel.new(name: 'some name', description: 'a description')

 ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
   No connection pool with 'primary' found.
```

Both the test and the development DB look fine when I inspect with PSQL

```
postgres-# \c test_doubles_test
You are now connected to database "test_doubles_test" as user "someusername".
test_doubles_test-# \dt
Did not find any relations.

test_doubles_test-# \c test_doubles_development
You are now connected to database "test_doubles_development" as user "someusername".
test_doubles_development-# \ct
invalid command \ct
Try \? for help.
test_doubles_development-# \dt
                  List of relations
 Schema |         Name         | Type  |    Owner    
--------+----------------------+-------+-------------
 public | ar_internal_metadata | table | testdoubles
 public | schema_migrations    | table | testdoubles
 public | some_models          | table | testdoubles
(3 rows)
```

Active Record is working as expected on the console

```
±  |master S:2 U:3 ?:2 ✗| → rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.2.2)
irb(main):001:0> SomeModel.count
   (2.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "some_models"
=> 0
irb(main)
```

config/database.yml

```
  default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: testdoubles
  password: <%= ENV['APPNAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: test_doubles_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_doubles_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: test_doubles_production
  username: test_doubles
  password: <%= ENV['TEST_DOUBLES_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Lastly, my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'rubocop-rails', require: false
gem 'sorbet-runtime'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'sorbet'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]


enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing require 'rails_helper' to load ActiveRecord into the spec.